# C# Outlook add-in randomly stops working, no errors

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have written what was a small add-in for Outlook that watches for emails being received, and then automatically prints the attachments if there are any, or the email itself if there are no attachments.

At first I had issues where if it was in the middle of processing an email and another email came in it would just skip it, so a lot of emails weren't getting printed. I tried multi-threading the app but Outlook just refused to open after that, kept giving some random error. So in the end I changed the add-in so that it just saves the attachments or email to a queue (a folder on the hdd), and then a console app goes through that queue printing the emails/attachments.

This all works great for a while, but then Outlook just stops reporting new emails to the application, and no errors are logged anywhere. Restarting Outlook gets it all working again, until a random time later (sometimes a couple of hours, sometimes a day) when it stops again. Its getting quite annoying because the purpose of the add-in is to reduce the amount of time sales spend printing orders, but this issue meant they had to keep checking print outs against emails received to determine which had or hadn't printed. I have now made a change so it automatically marks as read emails as they are printed so they can see when its stopped, but its still not perfect.

Does anyone know of a reason why Outlook might suddenly stop reporting new emails to this add-in? The code that runs (or is supposed to run) when a new email is received is:

```
        void outlookApp_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteToLog("Email Received: " + ((Outlook.MailItem)Application.Session.GetItemFromID((string)EntryIDCollection)).Subject);
            ProcessEmail(EntryIDCollection);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLog("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It doesn't even log "Email Received", and doesn't log an error in the catch block, so I don't think the event is even being triggered. Its not as if its being overloaded because the last email printed before the latest stop was the only one received for 19 hours (it was Saturday evening).

Any advice would be much appreciated - I'm getting hassle because what initially took me 15-30 minutes to write has now taken days with trying to get over all the various Microsoft isses.

EDIT:

The following is the WriteToLog method. I've just realised that the issue could potentially be the accessing of the log file, as both the add-in and console app use the same file, so could be trying to write to it at the same time.

```
    private void WriteToLog(string message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(logFile))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + message);
        }   
    }
```

I'm going to have a look into this now, and possibly create a second log file for the console app.

EDIT 2:

The following is how I'm subscribing to the event, within the "ThisAddin_Startup" method:

```
ApplicationClass outlookApp = new ApplicationClass();

        outlookApp.NewMailEx += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(outlookApp_NewMailEx);
```

Comment: What's in `ProcessEmail`?

Comment: Quite a lot, it basically saves the attachments to disk, or if there are none saves the body of the email to a .txt or .html file (depending if its an html email or not).

I can post the code here, but the fact it doesn't even write to the log that the email is received on the previous line to the call suggests its not getting as far as calling the method.

Comment: When it stops working, does the add-in get disabled by outlook, or does your add-in just stop working?

Comment: It still seems to be enabled, so it appears to be that Outlook has just stopped reporting new emails to the add-in. However, I've just put an update in my original post with the WriteToLog method - it could be that both the add-in and console app are trying to write to it at the same time.

Comment: How, and when, are you subscribing to the events?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that in - I've updated the original post with the code I'm using to subscribe.

Comment: I've just installed new versions of both the add-in and console app, which now use individual log files, hopefully this will fix the issue if it was indeed a conflict between both apps trying to write to the same log file at the same time. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Well, splitting the logs doesn't seem to have worked. Before I went out to lunch I checked and it had just stopped processing emails (there were some in the inbox showing unread, meaning they had not been processed by the add-in). I restarted it and it started processing them again, an hour later and it has stopped again. As before, no errors in the log, and nothing in the event log. Its as if Outlook has just decided to stop alerting the add-in to new emails.

Comment: which is the scope of outlookApp? function, class or application??